# How Google play store updates user apps automatically

Tags: android, android-intent, auto-update

How does Google play store app installs updates to the existing user apps ? I am trying to mimic a part of the functionality of Google play store, which is auto updating my app. I tried with the following approaches :

1) `Run adb command "install -r -g /sdcard/myapp.apk"` --> It failed giving the error:

> 'IOException:Error executing command'

2) `Intent i = Intent(Action_View); i.setDAtaAndType(Uri.fromFile("pathTomyapk");` But no luck, this intent launches a launcher which inturn asks user to install the updates.

I want to get rid of that launcher, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Build your own custom ROM, where your Play Store replacement is the designated market for the device, the way the Amazon AppStore for Android is on Fire devices.

There *might* be something for auto-update for devices that are part of Android for Work, though I haven't looked into that.

Otherwise, apps cannot silently update themselves, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Obviously I cannot build my own custom ROM. What am trying to achieve is to develop a simple user app which have to capability to update itself when an updated version is available. I gone thru your Github publishing here - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater which is similar to what am trying to achieve. Could you pls share any info on this ?

Comment: @Blanc: You are certainly welcome to download updates. However, the user has to be involved in installing the update, such as via your item #2 from your question. The discontinued cwac-updater project simply helped you detect when an update was available, download it, and arrange to install it when the user tapped on a `Notification` (IIRC, as it discontinued that project quite some time ago).

Comment: @ComonsWare: are you certain that we cannot update the app w/o the user's permission ? If that is the case How Google Play store is doing that in background w/o user's involvement ?

Comment: @Blanc: "are you certain that we cannot update the app w/o the user's permission ?" -- yes. "If that is the case How Google Play store is doing that in background w/o user's involvement ?" -- because the Play Store is part of the ROM and is given certain privileges as a result. This is why Amazon's ROM can have their own auto-update "store".

Comment: Appreciate your quick responses. Thank you! I found DeviceAdmin API which I thought may be useful. Am not sure, but would like to give a try with that.

Comment: Play Store can do it because it has the [INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#2067). This permission can only be acquired by apps that are signed with the ROM builder's key, *or* are installed as privileged apps (i.e., installed on /system/priv-app, which is normally not possible to add new apps to).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Appreciate your quick responses. Thank you. I came across DeviceAdmin API, which I believe may be useful.

Comment: @SnildDolkow Thank you Snild, Can we achieve using DeviceAdmin API ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: Not familiar with the DeviceAdmin API. Even if it does work, chances are your users will not be too keen on enabling your app as a Device Admin (it gives the app lots of power on the device!). Self-updates without asking the user is also a sure-fire way to make people annoyed. Is there a reason that you can't put the app on Play Store? And, if so, wouldn't a download+user manually clicking "install" suffice? As a user, I know I would prefer that behavior over automatic updates...

Comment: @Blanc: Device administrators cannot install apps silently.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes you are right. I didn't find a way to achieve this using this via Device Admin API.

Comment: @SnildDolkow This app is not for app store. It is for internal distrubution only and hence trying to force the auto update.

Comment: @CommonsWare : even with Android For Work, the update is not totally "silent", I tried it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://www.pushlink.com/

It has different update strategies that may be interesting for you. Of course, the "totally silent" update is only for rooted device, but the other more conventionnal strategies have the advantage of updating the app without neither leaving the app nor opening the Play Store to validate etc.

PS : I'm not affiliated to PushLink :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer for my question is - It's not possible. Atleast without rooting or without flashing a custom ROM. If you are trying on a rooting device probably the adb commands would work. If you are able to include your app in /system partition of a device then it is possible. For now Thanks for reading this.